# Cast to boolean, for integer linear programming

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming

I want to express the following constraint, in an integer linear program:

$$y = \begin{cases}
0 &\text{if } x=0\\
1 &\text{if } x\ne 0.
\end{cases}$$

I already have the integer variables $x,y$ and I'm promised that $-100 \le x \le 100$.  How can I express the above constraint, in a form suitable for use with an integer linear programming solver?

This will presumably require introducing some additional variables.  What new variables and constraints do I need to add?  Can it be done cleanly with one new variable?  Two?

Equivalently, this is asking how to enforce the constraint

$$y \ne 0 \text{ if and only if } x \ne 0.$$

in the context where I already have constraints that imply $|x| \le 100$ and $0 \le y \le 1$.

---

(My goal is to fix an error in https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/12118/755.)

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried working through some examples to see if you see a pattern? If yes, have you tried making a guess and then tried proving it?

Comment: Heh!  I see [what you did there](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/52008/#comment108521_52008), @Brika.  If you're curious to see what I tried, see [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/revisions/12118/5) as well as [this explanation of why that was actually wrong](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12102/#comment105773_12118).  If you want to see my next attempt, see [my answer](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/51062/755).  Thanks for reading through my old questions, and if they can be improved for the future, I'd love to hear any suggestions you might have!

Comment: That's very good.  ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I can do it with one extra binary variable $\delta \in \{0,1\}$:

$$
-100y \le x \le 100 y 
$$
$$
 0.001y-100.001\delta \le x \le -0.001y+100.001 (1-\delta) 
$$

**Update**

This assumes $x$ is a **continuous variable**. If we restrict $x$ to be **integer valued**, then the second constraint can be simplified to:
$$
 y-101\delta \le x \le -y+101 (1-\delta) 
$$

Comment: I verified this correct by testing it exhaustively with a little program.  Thank you for the solution!

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen, could you please explain the your logic with binary variable delta, for more general case, for instance, if y={a: x>0, b: x<0}.

Comment: @Nick The binary variable is used to model an 'OR' construct. See [here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/10/mip-modeling-if-constraint.html) for an answer to your question.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen, the great answer, I tried to applied the your approach to my question here http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/64794/how-to-move-logical-operator-or-from-an-objective-function-into-constraints-in-i.

Comment: Cool answer! However I think that you could avoid using that epsilon = 0.001 and just use epsilon = 1, so the inequality will look better without affecting the outcome, am I right? It would be: y - 101\delta <= x <= -y + 101(1-\delta)

Comment: @GonzaloSolera  You can make the 100.001 constant larger, but not smaller. For numerical reasons, I chose the smallest possible value. This is a standard big-M approach. The 0.001 constant should not be made 1. That would cause small values of $x$ to be infeasible when $y=1$.

Comment: @GonzaloSolera Actually I was wrong: I assumed $x$ to be a continuous variable. Indeed when $x$ is integer valued we can move 0.001 up to 1 as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

The following isn't pretty by any means, but it works. Let $0 \leq x \leq N$, $N=100$ in the specific case in the question. Then we have the following constraints.

1. $0 \leq z_1, z_2, z \leq 1$
2. $x - N(1-z_1) \leq 0$
3. $-x -Nz_1 \leq -1$
4. $-x -N(1-z_2) \leq 0$
5. $x -Nz_2 \leq -1$
6. $z_1 + z_2 - 1 \leq z$
7. $z \leq z_1$
8. $z \leq z_2$

The intuition is as follows. $z_1 = 1 \iff x \leq 0$. This is encoded in constraints 2 and 3. Similarly constraints 4 and 5 encode $z_2 = 1 \iff x \geq 0$. The last three constraints express $z = z_1 \land z_2$.

Comment: This seems to have a bug.  I assume you intend $z=1-y$.   However, it's still wrong for $x=100$: we want to force $y=1$ ($z=0$) in this case, but there's no choice for $z_1,z_2$ that satisfies all of the equations, as the equation $x-Nz_2 \le -1$ requires $x<N$ (i.e., $x \le 99$).    Thus, this ILP gives the wrong result when $x=99$: we want $y=1$, but we got $y=0$.  Also the desired range for $x$ as listed in the question is $-N \le x \le N$, not $0 \le x \le N$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses two temporary variables.  Let $t,u$ be integer zero-or-one variables, with the intended meaning that $t=1$ if $x \ge 0$, $u=1$ if $x \le 0$, and $y=\neg(t \land u)$.  These can be enforced with the following constraints:

$$\begin{align*}
0 &\le t,u,y \le 1\\
1+x &\le 101t \le 101 + x\\
1-x &\le 101u \le 101-x\\
t+u-1 &\le 1-y\\
1-y &\le t\\
1-y &\le u
\end{align*}$$

Comment: This answer is incorrect, unfortunately. It will constrain $x \leq 99$ by the first part of the first non-trivial constraint when the question asks given $x \leq 100$. Aren't fencepost errors fun? (Ditto for $x \geq -99$.)

Comment: @TLW, thank you for catching that!  I've edited my answer to fix the bug.  I tested it exhaustively with a little program and I think it should be correct now.