# How to solve an ILP problem with conditions in an objective function?

Tags: linear-programming, permutations, integer-programming

I have came accross this [link](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/51025/cast-to-boolean-for-integer-linear-programming?rq=1).

I have an integer linear programming (ILP) problem
$$\max_{(x_1, x_2,\ldots, x_n)}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\cdot f(x_i),$$

$$\text{subject to }  \begin{cases}
..., &(1)\\
L≤x_i≤U,&(2)\\
x_i \in \mathbb{Z}, i \in I,&(3)\\
\end{cases}
$$
here $X=\{x_i \in \mathbb{Z}: L \le x_i \le U,  L<0, U>0, i\in I\}$ is the variable, $I=\{1,2, \ldots, n\}$ is the set of indicies, the function $f(x_i)$ is defined as $$f(x_i) = \begin{cases}
a_i \in A, &\text{if } x_i>0, \\ 
b_i, \in B, &\text{if } x_i<0.\\
\end{cases}
$$ 
$A=\{a_i \in \mathbb{R}^+: a_i<a_{i+1}, \forall i= 1, 2, \ldots, n-1\}$, $B=\{b_i \in \mathbb{R}^+: b_i<b_{i+1}, \forall i=1,2,\ldots, n-1\}$ are the input (ordered) constants, such that $b_i <  a_i, i \in I$. In the system of constraints mentioned above the Eq.(1) means some extra constraints.

As the result I'd like to have the optimal solution $X^*$ and corresponded values of the $n$ input constants $a_i$ and $b_i$, $i \in I$.

**Question.** How to solve an ILP problem with the function $f(\cdot)$ in the objective function?

**Update 4.**

I think, I can obtain the result with next steps:

1) make a precomputing of the input constants: $C=\{c_{ji}, i \in I, j \in J\}$ is the set of permutations of $a_i$ and $b_i$, $J=\{1,2,\dots, 2^n\}$.

Let's  $A=(2.2, 4.4, 6.6)$ and $B=(1.1, 3.3, 5.5)$ then 
$$C=\left(%
\begin{array}{ccc}
        1.1 & 3.3 & 5.5 \\
        1.1 & 3.3 & 6.6 \\
        1.1 & 4.4 & 5.5 \\
        1.1 & 4.4 & 6.6\\ 
        2.2 & 3.3 & 5.5\\
        2.2 & 3.3 & 6.6\\
        2.2 & 4.4 & 5.5\\
        2.2 & 4.4 & 6.6\end{array}%
\right).$$

2) find the optimal solution $X^*_j$ of the $j$-th IPL problem from the set $$\max_{(x_1, x_2,\ldots, x_n)}\{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\cdot c_{ji}, j \in J\},$$
and apply $f(\cdot)$ to each element of $X^*$. For instance,

$X^*=\left(%
\begin{array}{ccc}
        -1 & 3 & 2 \\
        1 & -3 & 3 \\
        1 & -4 & 2 \\
        -1 & 4 & 1\\ 
        -2 & 3 & 2\\
        -2 & 3 & 5\\
      2 & -4 & 1\\
        2 & 4 & 1\end{array}%
\right),$
$f(X^*)=\left(%
\begin{array}{ccc}
        1.1 & 4.4 & 6.6 \\
        2.2 & 3.3 & 6.6 \\
        2.2 & 3.3 & 6.6 \\
        1.1 & 4.4 & 6.6\\ 
        1.1 & 4.4 & 6.6\\
        1.1 & 4.4 & 6.6\\
        2.2 & 3.3 & 5.5\\
        2.2 & 4.4 & 6.6\end{array}%
\right).$

3) match the elements of $C$ and $f(X^*)$ by rows: $Res=if(C==f(X^*),1,0)$. In the example the $4$-th and $6$-th rows were matched only (denoted by 1's):

$$Res=\left(%
\begin{array}{ccc}
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        1 & 1 & 1\\ 
        0 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0\\
        1 & 1 & 1\end{array}%
\right),$$

4) select the maximum from the values of objective functions for the matched rows only:

$\max_{(x_1, x_2,\ldots, x_n)}\{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\cdot c_{ji}, j =\{4,6\} \}=\max(-1\cdot 1.1 + 4 \cdot 4.4 + 1 \cdot 6.6, 2\cdot 2.2 + 4 \cdot 4.4 + 1 \cdot 6.6 )=\max(23.1, 28.6)=28.6$. Thus, the optimal solution of the intial ILP is: $X^*=(2,4,6)$ which corresponds to the input constants $(a_1, a_2, a_3)=(2.2,4.4,6.6)$.

**The weak points are:**

1. How to prove that you will have at least one matched pair on the step 3?
2. How to match elements $C$ and $f(X^*)$ if $f(X^*_{ij})=0$ on the step 2?

Answer (score 1):

Introduce integer variables $x^+_i,x^-_i,y_i$, where each $y_i$ is 0 or 1.  The intended meaning of $y_i$ is that $y_i=1$ means $x_i$ is positive, $y_i=0$ means $x_i$ is zero or negative; and that $x^+_i$ captures the positive part of $x_i$ and $x^-_i$ captures the negative part.  We'll enforce that intention by adding the following constraints:

$$\begin{gather*}
x_i = x^+_i + x^-_i\\
0 \le x^+_i \le U \cdot y_i\\
L \cdot (1-y_i) \le x^-_i \le 0\\
0 \le y_i \le 1
\end{gather*}$$

This ensures that the $x_i,y_i,x^+_i,x^-_i$ are consistent.  Finally, note that

$$x_i \cdot f(x_i) = a_i x^+_i + b_i x^-_i,$$

so the objective function can be expressed as

$$\sum_i a_i x^+_i + b_i x^-_i,$$

which is a linear function of the variables.  Now maximize this objective function subject to the constraints above and any other constraints you might have, by feeding it to any ILP solver.

See [Express boolean logic operations in zero-one integer linear programming (ILP)](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/12102/755) for other tricks of the trade.

Comment: Thanks you for the elegant answer, I should test it before accept. Could you please clarify the limits of index $i$ in you answer? Is there $i \in \{1,2,\ldots, n\}$ always?

Comment: @Nick, yes, that's right.