# Converting If-else condition to Linear Programming

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming

I have a constraint in a linear programming formulation with two variables: $X \ge Y$

To which I want to apply the following if-else conditions:

```
if Y=1:
    X=1
else:
    X=0
```

Where $X$ and $Y$ are binary.

How can I fit this if-else into linear programming? Do I need to define another variable? It looks as an AND operation, between $X$ and $Y$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be expressed with just the equation $X=Y$.  Since $X,Y$ are zero-or-one variables, the only possible assignments that are consistent with your condition are $X=Y=0$ and $X=Y=1$.

See [Express boolean logic operations in zero-one integer linear programming (ILP)](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/12102/755) for many more boolean conditions and how to express them as linear inequalities.