# Linear programming, Checking a constraint based on condition

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming

I have a constraint $X \ge Y$ in a Linear programming formulation, where both $X$ and $Y$ are binary. I want to check this constraint on a condition like:

```
if (Y==1)
      then check the constraint
else
      Don't care about the constraint
```

How to do it.

Comment: Check [page 7](http://mixedintegerprogramming.weebly.com/uploads/1/4/1/8/14181742/integer_programming_tricks_-_aimms_modeling_guide.pdf)

Comment: You do it by introducing a large number, say $M$, and writ $X+(1-Y)M\geqslant Y$.

Comment: If $Y=1$ then $X$ must be greater than or equal to $1$ and since $X$ is binary, then you must have that $X=1$. So there is no need to introduce a large number $M$. You can simply write $X\geqslant Y$. In case $Y=1$, you get $X=1$ and in case $Y=0$, you have no restriction on $X$.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/67459/755.  That other question asks about `if Y==1: X=1 else: X=0`.  That's a different situation.  The solution listed for the other question doesn't solve this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are zero-or-one (binary) integer variables, then this is encoded as

$$X \ge Y.$$

Why does this work?  If $Y=1$, then this enforces the constraint $X \ge Y$, as you wanted.  If $Y=0$, this enforces the constraint $X \ge 0$, i.e., it doesn't impose any rstrictions on $X$, which is also as you wanted.

In general, conditional constraints can be handled using the techniques found on page 7 of [AIMMS Modeling Guide - Integer Programming Tricks](http://mixedintegerprogramming.weebly.com/uploads/1/4/1/8/14181742/integer_programming_tricks_-_aimms_modeling_guide.pdf), which is a helpful tutorial on how to encode constraints in integer programming.  Thanks to @adrianN for pointing to that resource.

You can also take a look at https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/12118/755 and at [Formulating Integer Linear Programs: A Rogues' Gallery](http://faculty.nps.edu/dell/docs/Formulettes060425.pdf) for other techniques and practice problems.