# Linear Programming if-then-else

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I have a binary variable $y\ \epsilon\ \{0,1\} $ and a real $x$ which has the following boundaries $-100\leq\ x \leq\ 100$. How can I reformulate the following statement:
$$
y = 
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $ x<  0  $ }\\
1 & \text{if $x \geq0$}\\
\end{cases}
$$

Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the form of *any* "statement" in an LP? Note also that IP ≠ LP; you can't simulate discrete variables fully with (polynomially sized) LPs (since solving IPs is NP-hard in general).

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/76549/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/71091/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/67163/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/12102/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/67632/755