# Big M method for continuous variables

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, constraint-satisfaction

Is there any way to model the big M method for continuous variables?
Something similar to [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/69531/greater-than-condition-in-integer-linear-program-with-a-binary-variable) but $B, C \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ and $A\in\{0,1\}$.

Due to the precision problem, when the $B$ and $C$ are close I do not get the correct answer.

Let $p_{i,j} \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, for $i=1,\dots, n, j=1, \dots, m$. As one of the constraints of my problem, I am looking for $h$ such that
$$
  g_i(h) := \sum_{j=1}^h p_{i,j} < 1.
$$
To find $h$, I defined  $a_{i,j} \in \{0,1\}$  such that 
$$
a_{i,h} = 
\begin{cases}
1 \qquad \text{if } g_i(h) < 1 \quad h=1, \dots, m, \\
0 \qquad \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

To implement the if condition above, I used the big-M method, but the problem is that the big-M method works well for ILPs while the variable, here $p$, is non-integer.
When $g_i(h)$ is very close to 1 but not absolutely 1 due to the precision of the number, say $ g_i(h)=1-10^{-16}$, then $g_i(h)$ which actually is 1 will not be assumed as 1 by the program, and the program does not return the correct value for $h$.
I was wondering if there is a trick for this issue.

Comment: What's the "big M method"?

Comment: "I do not get the correct answer". Whenever you get an error, it is almost compulsory to write it out in detail. Please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Apass.Jack I have updated the question. As I told, a similar question is here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/69531/greater-than-condition-in-integer-linear-program-with-a-binary-variable

Comment: This seems more appropriate for [scicomp.se].