# How to model equality in Integer Linear Programming

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming, mathematical-programming, constraint-programming

How to implement v=(a==b) using Linear Programming?
$$
v=
\begin{cases}
True, a=b\\
False, a≠b\\
\end{cases}
$$

Until now I tried the big M-Method.

To show a≤b:
$$a-b+Mv≤M$$
$$-a+b-Mv≤-1$$

To show b≤a:
$$-a+b+Mv≤M$$
$$a-b-Mv≤-1$$

When they are equal everything is okay, but when a≠b it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Cast to boolean, for integer linear programming](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/51025/755), setting $x=a-b$ and $y=v$.  This only works if you have a constant upper bound on $|a-b|$.  Otherwise, I don't know how to express it in an ILP.

See also [Express boolean logic operations in zero-one integer linear programming (ILP)](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/12102/755), [Boolean variable true iff equation is satisfied in ILP](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/67163/755), [Boolean variable that captures whether an inequality holds](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/104990/755).

Comment: I forgot to mention because I thought it was irrelevant but 1<=|a|,|b|<=10.