# IF THEN condition in Linear Program

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming

I have the following condition in an LP problem. I have a variable $x_i \in i = 1,2,..7$ and I need to constrain the problem via:

if $x_1$ >5 then $x_2 \leq 30$

I'm stumped on how to formulate that with integer variables.

Thanks

Comment: Call $y\in\{0,1\}$ a binary variable and consider $x_1-Ay\leq 5, x_2-A(1-y)\leq 30$, where $A$ is a very large constant.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/104990/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/67163/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/12102/755

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate it.