# ILP representation of the number of maximal 1 sequences in a row

Tags: algorithms, linear-programming, integer-programming, substrings, subsequences

I am currently using an ILP to model events which occur on some input sequence from $1...n$. These events modify the input sequence in order to obtain a desired sequence. Each event can happen on some consecutive range $(i,j)$ and no two events can overlap. Therefore, I can represent events by some matrix $a=\{0, 1\}^{n\times n}$ where $a_{i,j} = 1$ iff there is an event that begins at $i$ and ends at $j$ ($i<=j$).

Unfortunately, this results in $O(n^2)$ variables and in some cases $O(n^3)$ or greater number of constraints. It would be ideal if instead I could represent these events as a row $a'=\{0,1\}^n$, where $a'_i = 1 \iff \exists a_{p,q}\quad  \text{s.t.}\quad  p\leq i\leq q \land a_{p,q} = 1$
i.e. a position $a'_i=1$ iff there is an event that modifies position $i$.

Since I am optimizing over the number of events, at the moment I am minimizing $\sum a_{p,q}$, since it represents the number of events. If I ditch $a$ and try to only use $a'$, I am left with some row, for example $a'=[1,1,0,...,1,0,1]$.

**Question 1:** I want to represent the total number of events given $a'$. Currently, I am thinking $\sum a_i(1-a_{i+1})$ to count the number of "ends" of events. Obviously I can deal with the edge case as well. Unfortunately, this results in a product of binary variables. I know that I can represent this with a helper variable, and just sum over that, but I was wondering if there was any more efficient ways.

**Question 2:** This question is more important, since my whole model revolves around this. An event will only affect the input elements **after** the end of the event. Think of events as duplications. If some range $(i,j)$ is duplicated, all elements **after** $j$ would shift to the right by $j-i+1$ slots. Following this idea of events being duplications, consider the input below:

$a,b,c,d,e$ and the desired sequence $a,b,a,b,c,d,e,d,e$. We can achieve this by duplicating $a,b$ and $d,e$ i.e. $a'=[1,1,0,1,1]$. Notice how positions $0$ and $1$ did not shift at all, positions $2,3,4,5,6$ were originally $0,1,2,3,4$, and positions $7$ and $8$ were originally $3$ and $4$.

Essentially, for every position $i$ in the resulting sequence, I would like to be able to determine which position $j$ it came from in the original sequence. Consider position $6$ in the resulting sequence, we can clearly see it came from position $4$. We notice that this shift of $2$. Similarly, position $5$ came from position $3$. A pattern unfolds such that the shift of position $i$ is always equal to the $\sum_{j<k} a'_j$ where $k$ is the largest index such that $k\leq i \land a_k=0$. This is the same as saying that we are taking the sum of all values of $a'$ up to the most recent $0$ before or at $i$ in $a'$.

How can I model such shifting in an ILP? I.e. given $a’$, how can I create a variable $h$ in the ILP such that $h_{r, l}=1$ iff $\sum_{j<k} a'_j= l$ where $k$ is the largest index such that $k\leq r \land a_k=0$.

Comment: For question 1, a helper variable is a natural way to do this.  You'll end up with only $2n$ variables, which is still far less than $n^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be done with $9n$ variables, instead of $n^2$.  Define the following integer variables for use in your linear program:

- $a_i = 1$ if index $i$ is within an event
- $s_i = 1$ if an event starts at index $i$
- $e_i = 1$ if an event ends at index $i$
- $c_i = $ the number of positions until the end of this event (so that index $i+c_i-1$ is the end of the event containing $i$), if $i$ is in an event, or $0$ if $i$ is not in an event
- $d_i = $ is how many positions since the start of the event (so that index $i-d_i+1$ is the start of the event containing $i$), if $i$ is in an event, or $0$ if $i$ is not in an event
- $\ell^1_i = $ the length of the event containing $i$, if $i$ is the end of an event, or $0$ if $i$ is not the end of an event
- $\ell^2_i = $ the length of the event containing $i$, if $i$ is the start of an event, or $0$ if $i$ is not the start of an event
- $o^1_i = $ the amount index $i$ is shifted when copying to the new array, for the first copy of that element
- $o^2_i = $ the amount index $i$ is shifted when copying to the new array, for the second copy of that element

These can be enforced with the following equations:

- $s_i = a_i \land \neg a_{i-1}$ (see [Express boolean logic operations in zero-one integer linear programming (ILP)](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/12102/755) for how to enforce this)
- $e_i = a_i \land \neg a_{i+1}$
- $c_i \ge c_{i+1} + 1 - n s_{i-1}$, $c_i \le c_{i+1} + 1$, $c_i \le n a_i$, $c_i \ge e_i$, $c_i \ge 0$
- $d_i \ge d_{i-1} + 1 - n e_{i-1}$, $d_i \le d_{i-1} + 1$, $d_i \le n a_i$, $d_i \ge s_i$, $d_i \ge 0$
- $\ell^1_i \le n e_i$, $\ell^1_i \ge d_i - n(1-e_i)$, $\ell^1_i \ge 0$
- $\ell^2_i \le n s_i$, $\ell^2_i \ge c_i - n (1-s_i)$, $\ell^2_i \ge 0$
- $o^1_i = o^1_{i-1} + \ell^1_{i-1}$, $o^1_0 = 0$
- $o^2_i = o^2_{i-1} + \ell^2_i$, $o^2_0 = 0$

Then the total number of events is $s_1+\dots+s_n$, and you can model shifting as follows: index $i$ in the original array is shifted to indices $i+o^1_i$ and $i+o^2_i$ in the new array.

Do check my work carefully. There could easily be off-by-one errors or other mistakes in the above.

Comment: I am trying to use the basic idea of your formulation to make my own, before I spoil it for myself. One thing that I wonder, though:

For $\ell_i^1$ and $\ell_i^2$, what is the benefit to representing these as integers, instead of instead having, for example, combining $e_i$ and $l_i^1$ into a $n\times n$ matrix where $e_{i,\ell}=1$ if and only if there is an event of size $\ell$ ending at position $i$?

Clearly, we go from $n$ variables to $n^2$, but I also (mis)remember reading that having large factors in constraints may make the LP harder to solve. Something about the Big M method.

Comment: @BryceKille, I'm trying to use only $O(n)$ variables instead of $O(n^2)$ variables.  I think you're exactly right about the potential downsides.  I don't know whether ILP will be more efficient with $O(n)$ variables and big constants vs $O(n^2)$ variables and small constants; the only way to find out might be to implement both and benchmark them.  If you're willing to use $O(n^2)$ variables, there might be simpler ways to model your situation.

Comment: Great! I'll do that and get back to you on this post. I have another questions which I will write below. Thank you for all of your help.

I am wondering if the use of $c_i$ and $d_i$ are necessary. They are only used for constructing $\ell$. I believe the $\ell$s can be constructed without them. $\ell^1_r = (\sum_{i\leq r}a_i - \sum_{i<r}\ell_i^1)e_r$ and $\ell_r^2=(\sum_{i\geq r}a_i - \sum_{i > r}\ell^2_I)s_r.$ Both of these products of some big M and a binary variable can be broken down into linear constraints. I believe this checks out.

Comment: I don't want a yes/no answer on the correctness, necessarily. I know that's not what this site is for. However, again I'm wondering if you have any insight as to the performance of the tradeoff of less variables, but constraints which now include a sum of $O(n)$ variables. Do you know if most LP implementations avoid recomputing the sum for every index and instead just do a parallel prefix? (The latter question may be better suited for another SE)

Comment: @BryceKille, those constraints aren't linear -- the term $a_i e_r$ is a quadratic term.  So, they can't appear in an ILP.  I don't have any insight into that tradeoff, sadly.

Comment: Hmm, so I [have seen](https://www.leandro-coelho.com/linearization-product-variables/) that we can take some constraint $z = A\times x$ where $x\in \{0,1\}$ and $0\leq A\leq M$ and convert it to the following constraints (1):$ z\leq Mx$ (2): $z\leq A$ (3): $z\geq A - (1-x)M$ (4): $z\geq 0$ 

Why does that not work here, where $z=\ell_r^1$, $A=\sum_{i\leq r}a_i - \sum_{i<r}\ell_i^1$, and $x=e_r$, since we have the bound on $0\leq A \leq (r+1)$

Comment: @BryceKille, oh, I think it does work here;  I didn't know about that trick before now.  (I didn't check the details carefully but it looks good to me.)  Nice!  Thank you for showing me that.