# Linear program for min-length pair of edge-disjoint paths problem

Tags: graphs, shortest-path, linear-programming, integer-programming

Consider a problem: we have an undirected graph $G = (V, E)$, function $l: E \to \mathbb{Z}_{+}$ where $l(e)$ is edge's length $e \in E$, and two vertices $s$ and $t$. And we want to find a pair $(A, B)$ of edge-disjoint paths between $s$ and $t$ such that
$$
\sum_{e \in A}l(e) + \sum_{e \in B} l(e) \to \min
$$
How can I formulate this problem in terms of ILP ?

Comment: Can you tell us the context where you encountered this task?  Is it a practical problem?  Did you encounter it in a textbook or exercise?  Is there any particular reason you want a solution using ILP specifically?  What approaches to encoding as ILP have you considered and what difficulties did you encounter?  https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/12102/755 may be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can be solved in polynomial time by finding a [minimum-cost maximum flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem) in the graph, where you set the capacity of each edge to $1$ and the cost of each edge $e$ to $-l(e)$, and add a source node $s_0$ with an edge $s_0 \to s$ of capacity 2 and cost 0.  (You might need to add a "demand" that the edge $s_0 \to s$ has exactly 2 units of flow along it.)

If you must formulate it as an ILP, introduce a zero-or-one variable $x_e$ for each edge, with the intended semantics that $x_e=1$ means that edge $e$ is in the first path.  Add a constraint that, for each vertex $v$ other than the source/sink, $\sum_w x_{(v,w)}$ is 0 or 2; for the source and sink, it must be 1.  This captures the requirement that you have a path from $s$ to $t$.  Add another zero-or-one variable $y_e$ for each edge, with similar constraints to ensure it represents a path from $s$ to $t$.  Finally, enforce the disjointness requirement: $x_e + y_e \le 1$.  The objective function to maximize is $\sum_e l(e) x_e + l(e) y_e$.

You can enforce a constraint that a variable $z$ is 0 or 2 by requiring $z=2t$ where $0\le t \le 1$ is a fresh zero-or-one integer variable.

Comment: I learned a lot from this answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Very interesting solution

Comment: @InuyashaYagami, fixed, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Optimization Function:** *minimize* $\sum_{e \in E} l(e) \cdot x_{1}(e) + \sum_{e \in E} l(e) \cdot x_{2}(e)$

**Constraints:** $$\sum_{(u,v) \in C} x_{1}(u,v) \geq 1 \quad \textrm{for every $(s,t)$ cut $C$ in the graph}$$
$$\sum_{(u,v) \in C} x_{2}(u,v) \geq 1 \quad \textrm{for every $(s,t)$ cut $C$ in the graph}$$
$$x_{1}(u,v) + x_{2}(u,v) \leq 1 \quad \textrm{for every edge $(u,v) \in E$}$$
$$x_{1}(u,v), x_{2}(u,v) \in \{0,1\} \quad \textrm{for every edge $(u,v) \in E$}$$
**Correctness:**

- For an edge $e = (u,v)$, $x_{1}(e) = 1$ denotes if $e$ is in the path $A$; otherwise $x_{1}(e) = 0$. Similarly, $x_{2}(e) = 1$ denotes if $e$ is in the path $B$; otherwise $x_{1}(e) = 0$. Note that I have used the variables $x_{1}(e)$ and $x_{1}(u,v)$ interchangebly.
- The first constraint is for path $A$ from $s$ to $t$.
- The second constraint is for path $B$ from $s$ to $t$.
- The third constraint makes the paths $A$ and $B$ disjoint.

Comment: There can be exponentially many cuts, so this can give an exponential-size encoding.  That doesn't seem very satisfying.

Comment: @D.W. Agreed. I am trying to think of a solution with the polynomial number of constraints. That might require the shortest path LP formulation that indeed has the polynomial number of constraints.

Comment: @InuyashaYagami I've also tried to build ILP using max-flow LP formulation, think it could be useful here

Comment: @InuyashaYagami can you please explain your ideas about solution with the polynomial number of constraints?

Comment: @envygrunt It is possible to formulate the shortest path problem from $(s,t)$ using an LP with the polynomial number of constraints. See Section 29.2 of CLRS (link: https://edutechlearners.com/download/Introduction_to_algorithms-3rd%20Edition.pdf).

Comment: @envygrunt In your question, there is two disjoint paths whose cost we want to minimize. It looks like an extension of the shortest path problem. That is all the ideas I have till now.