# Encoding a binary sequence with shift in MILP

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming, constraint-programming

I would like to know if it's actually possible to encode a (binary) sequence with rotations in MILP/MIP.

Given a binary sequence $(0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1)$ and variables $x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6,x_7$
I want to restrict my MILP program such that it takes up one of the following:
\begin{align}
(x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6,x_7) & = (0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1)\text{ or} \\
(x_7,x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6) & = (0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1)\text{ or} \\
(x_6,x_7,x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5) & = (0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1)\text{ or} \\ 
\vdots \\
(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6,x_7,x_0) & = (0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1)
\end{align}

I understand that the rotation can be easily solved by just extending the sequence. But I find myself creating multiple MILP instances, each instance corresponding to exactly one of the cases. If this is infeasible, why?

Comment: Why do you need linear programming for this?

Comment: It is part of a bigger problem I am currently working on and I require the sequence to be enforced in it. I have worked out a CP model as well. However, due to the large search space, MILP is faster in converging to an optimal solution. Thus, I was interested in the feasibility of such formulation.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/12102/755

Answer (score 1):

In constraint programming this particular type of constraint is known as a [table constraint](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.5.5/en/lib-globals.html#index-159). It is generally said to be an existential constraint, since many other constraints can be encoded using a table constraint. As such, it is often better to use the underlying structure when possible (I don't see a way around it in this case), although tables have been proven to be very effective in constraint programming solvers.

To encode a table constraint in MILP, the generally idea is to create a new zero one variable $s$ for every row in the table that signifies whether the row is selected. There are then two kinds of constraints.
$$
\sum_{i \in rows} s_i = 1
$$

$$
\sum_{j \in col} table_{ij}*s_i = x_i    ,\forall_{i \in rows} 
$$

This is how the MiniZinc constraint modelling language would also encode this constraint for MILP solvers: https://github.com/MiniZinc/libminizinc/blob/master/share/minizinc/linear/fzn_table_int.mzn