# ILP - Maximize the number of pairs of variables with the same value

Tags: optimization, np-complete, combinatorics, linear-programming, integer-programming

I have a **0-1** integer linear program for a set of $2n$ variables $S = \{x_1, ..., x_n, y_1, ..., y_n\}$. My objective is to maximize the number of pairs $(x_i, y_i)$ such that $x_i = y_i$, $i = 1, ..., n$.

$$
\max \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{1}(x_i = y_i)
$$

where $\mathbb{1}(x_i = y_i) = 1$ if and only if $x_i = y_i$, $i = 1, ..., n$.

The constraints are not important in this context. You may think the only constraints are:
$$x_i \in \{0, 1\}, y_i \in \{0, 1\}, i = 1, ..., n$$

Obviously, this objective is not linear w.r.t the variables. I am wondering if there is a workaround (e.g., additional constraints) to construct a different objective function that is (1) linear and (2) also maximizes the number of such pairs of variables.

Comment: You can keep it linear by introducing $z_i$ for each $i$ and adding $2n$ constraints: $z_i\ge x_i-y_i$ and $z_i\ge y_i-x_i$ and then change the objective to minimize the sum of the $z_i$.

Comment: https://blog.adamfurmanek.pl/2015/09/19/ilp-part-5/

Comment: @TickaJules Bravo! This really helps!

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/12102/755

Comment: Perhaps you can answer your own question now?