# Find the placement of gates on 2D points that minimizes the total distance of all paths to be made

Tags: algorithms, graphs, optimization, euclidean-distance

Suppose we have a 6 vertices graph. We also have 6 gates. Each gate is attributed a path.

For example,

Gate 'A' will have to go to 'B'- 'C' - 'D' and 'E'

Gate 'B' will have to go to 'D'

Gate 'C' will have to go to 'A' and 'B'

Gate 'D' will have to go to 'E' - 'A' and 'B'

Gate 'E' will have to go to 'C' - 'E' and 'A'

Gate 'B' will have to go to 'D'

How can I find the optimal placement of the gates on the graph, such that it makes the least distance overall, computing all the paths to be made?

For 6 gates, we could search all possible placements by brute force. However, in my current project I have 42 gates to dispatch, thus it sounds too complicated to brute force.

The following is the function used to calculate the distance between the two gates (stocked in a Pandas DataFrame)

```python
import math
def calculateDistance(df, gate_a, gate_b):
    coord_a = [(x, df.columns[y]) for x, y in zip(*np.where(df.values == gate_a))][0] # GET COORDINATE OF GATE_A
    coord_b = [(x, df.columns[y]) for x, y in zip(*np.where(df.values == gate_b))][0] # GET COORDINATE OF GATE_B
    y1, x1 = coord_a[0], coord_a[1]
    y2, x2 = coord_b[0], coord_b[1]
    dist = math.sqrt((((x2 - x1) * scale_x) **2)  + ( ((y2 - y1) * scale_y) **2 ))
    return dist
    
calculateDistance(df, "A", "C")
```

Comment: I've added the way I calculate the distance between two gates, finding the gate's coordinates within the dataframe.

Comment: The least distance overall, computing all the paths to be made! Sorry if this is not clear

Comment: No, in my current project I have  42 gates to dispatch, thus it sounds too complicated to brute force

Comment: [Travelling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Euclidean) is a very special case of your task. It is unlikely there is an algorithm in polynomial time of the number of gates.

Comment: Let me do my best attempt to rephrase the problem in CS terms: There's a metric space $X$, with $n$ points. Additionally, there is a collection of $n$ sequences of labels, where all labels are numbers in $\{1, \ldots, n\}$, and all sequences start with a different label. When the points are labeled in bijection to $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ then each sequence defines a path. The problem is to choose a bijective labeling of the nodes that minimizes the sum of the lengths of paths induced by the sequences? Is this a correct interpretation? If so your problem is clearly NP-hard as suggested by @JohnL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [the reformulation of your problem from Bernardo Subercaseaux](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/153209/find-the-placement-of-gates-on-2d-points-that-minimizes-the-total-distance-of-al#comment322379_153209), your problem is NP-hard (as [John L explains](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/153209/find-the-placement-of-gates-on-2d-points-that-minimizes-the-total-distance-of-al#comment322375_153209)), so you should not expect an algorithm that will be efficient in the worst case.

That said, 42 is a fairly small number, so there is some hope.  I would suggest that you formulate this as an instance of integer linear programming (ILP).  Add zero-or-one boolean variables $x_{v,i}$ for each vertex $v$ (i.e., point in the plane) and each gate $i$ (i.e., each index in $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$), where $x_{v,i}=1$ means that $v$ is associated with $i$.  Add constraints to enforce that this is a bijective mapping, i.e., $\sum_v x_{v,i}=1$ for all $i$ and $\sum_i x_{v,i}=1$ for all $v$.  Also, for each $v,w,i,j$ let $y_{v,i,w,j} = x_{v,i} \land x_{w,j}$, which can be enforced using linear inequalities as explained in [Express boolean logic operations in zero-one integer linear programming (ILP)](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/12102/755).  Finally, you now have an objective $\Phi$ defined as

$$\Phi = \sum_{i,j} \sum_v \sum_w d(v,w) y_{v,i,w,j}$$

where $d(v,w)$ is the distance between $v$ and $w$ (a constant), and you sum over all edges $(i,j)$ that appear in the input sequences, and you sum over all possible $v$ and $w$.  This objective is a linear function, so you can use an ILP solver to find the solution that minimizes $\Phi$.  You'll end up with an ILP instance with several million variables and tens of millions of inequalities, which might be small enough that an off-the-shelf ILP solver can solve it to find a decent solution.