# Nesting algorithm for rectangular-based, fixed-orientation polygons

Tags: linear-programming, packing

I'm looking for an algorithm that is closely related to the [2-dimensional nesting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nesting_%28process%29) (also known as lay planning, bin packing, and the cutting stock problem).

The main differences between this and normal nesting are:

- A fixed number of elements to be placed
- The elements cannot rotate
- The elements must be placed in as *small* an area as possible, as opposed to placing as *many* pieces as possible in a fixed-size area.
- The elements are rectangular pieces with 0-4 fixed-orientation rectangular corner cutouts ([“Utah-like”](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4573906/480381)), as opposed to being randomly shaped

**Input:** *`n`* “Utah-like”, fixed-orientation polygons. *`n`* is in the range 1-20. The figures are *not* shaped to align perfectly with each other. Example figure set:

[image]

**Desired output:** A fixed-orientation nesting for a scaleable area with predefined proportions. The scaleable area should be scaled to fit the nested figures as snugly as possible, like so:

[image]

Note the area where the figures' rectangular boundaries overlap, preventing this from being a more trivial [rectangle-packing problem](https://codeincomplete.com/articles/bin-packing/).

I have perused several packing questions on SE (e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56922815/what-algorithm-can-be-used-for-packing-of-regular-shapes-on-the-a1-sized-sheet-i), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48609658/python-2d-packing-irregular-shapes-one-by-one), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864382/packing-arbitrary-polygons-within-an-arbitrary-boundary)) as well as puzzle-solving questions (e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121903/algorithm-for-solving-tiling-jigsaw-puzzle), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70768805/i-wish-to-calculate-all-possible-solutions-for-this-wooden-puzzle-game), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33052158/algorithm-to-assemble-a-simplified-jigsaw-puzzle-where-all-edges-are-identified)), and also outside Stack Exchange ([1](https://gorillasun.de/blog/a-simple-solution-for-shape-packing-in-2d), [2](https://ufdc.ufl.edu/UFE0000907/00001), [3](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226000523_TOPOS_-_A_new_constructive_algorithm_for_nesting_problems)), but they don't describe this particular problem or don't include source code. Related GitHub repos: [1](https://github.com/Athlici/Packing), [2](https://github.com/Jack000/SVGnest), [3](https://github.com/sasam2/nesting). Online solvers: [SVGnest.com](https://svgnest.com) and [Nestable.xyz](https://www.nestable.xyz/nestable-app/).

Answer (score 3):

I will describe how you can solve this with an ILP (integer linear programming) solver.  For the size of problem you have, I expect it will work acceptably well.

Let's focus on just two of your shapes, say shape $S_i$ and $S_j$.  Let $(x_i,y_i)$ denote the position of some fixed point of $S_i$  (say, the lower-left corner), and $(x_j,y_j)$ the position of some fixed point of $S_j$.  Then it is possible to write down a formula $\Phi_{i,j}$ that captures the condition that $S_i,S_j$ do not overlap.  This formula will have the form

$$(x_j-x_i \ge \alpha_1 \land y_j-y_i \ge \beta_1) \lor \cdots (x_j-x_i \ge \alpha_k \land y_j-y_i \ge \beta_k),$$

except that some $\ge$'s might be replaced with $\le$.  Here the $\alpha,\beta$ values are constants that can be easily calculated from the shapes $S_i,S_j$.  We can express $\Phi_{i,j}$ in a form suitable for use with an ILP solver using the methods in [Express boolean logic operations in zero-one integer linear programming (ILP)](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/12102/755).  In particular, we can encode $\Phi_{i,j}$ as the linear inequalities

$$\begin{align*}
x_j-x_i &\ge \alpha_1 - C(1-t_1)\\
y_j-y_i &\ge \beta_1 - C(1-t_1)\\
&\vdots\\
x_j-x_i &\ge \alpha_k - C(1-t_k)\\
y_j-y_i &\ge \beta_k - C(1-t_k)\\
t_1 + \cdots + t_k &\ge 1 
\end{align*}$$

except that whenever you replace $\ge$ with $\le$, you also replace $-C(1-t_u)$ with $+C(1-t_u)$.  Here, $t_1,\dots,t_k$ are fresh new variables that are specific to $\Phi_{i,j}$, and they are constrained to be integers and constrained to be 0 or 1 (via the inequalities $0 \le t_1 \le 1$, etc.)  Also $C$ is a large constant.

Finally, introduce a variable $z$, which represents the width of the containing rectangle.  The containing rectangle's height will be $\gamma z$ where $\gamma$ is a known constant (the aspect ratio).

Add constraints to ensure that all shapes fit within the rectangle $[0,z] \times [0,\gamma z]$.  In particular, for shape $S_i$, we obtain inequalities on $x_i,y_i$ (something like $0 \le x_i \le z-\text{width}(S_i)$, $0 \le y_i \le \gamma z - \text{height}(S_i)$ if $(x_i,y_i)$ is the lower-left corner of $S_i$, but the exact inequalities may vary depending on which fixed point of $S_i$ you chose).

Add the linear inequalities for each $\Phi_{i,j}$, for every pair $i,j$ with $i\ne j$.

The objective function is to minimize $z \ge 0$.

Finally, solve the resulting ILP instance obtained in this way.  This should give you an optimal nesting.

Comment: This seems like a great lead! I have no previous experience with integer linear programming, but your answer has motivated me to start on a primer :-)

Comment: This answer is supported by [this comment on GitHub](https://github.com/Athlici/Packing/issues/3#issuecomment-1320396087)

Comment: D.W., do you know of any repository with ILP code for bin packing, strip packing or nesting? E.g. written in Python or JavaScript? My thought was to try and implement a more basic ILP strip packing proof of concept (PoC) first, and then work on the more complex nesting problem if I could solve the PoC.